# Is there a way to avoid generation of duplicate entries?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, backend

I have setup a express backend where i have to code my routes myself.For the POST route we have to make sure that name isnt already present in the hardcoded array before we accept it.I used the some function for this and its working to some extent.It throws an error after taking the duplicate entry once,is there a way to prevent this initial duplication too?

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.use(express.json())

let persons = [
    {
        "name": "Dan Abramov",
        "number": "12-43-234345",
        "id": 1
      },
      {
        "name": "Mary Poppendieck",
        "number": "39-23-6423122",
        "id": 2
      },
      {
        "name": "Kshitij Tapre ",
        "number": "81131381",
        "id": 3
      }
]

app.post('/api/persons', (req, res) => {
  const person = req.body
  const chkname=person.name
  console.log(persons.some(e1=>e1.name===chkname))
  if (persons.some(e1=>e1.name===chkname)) {
    res.status(406).send('Name already exists')    
  }else{
    if (person.name&&person.number) {
      person.id=genId(persons)
      persons = persons.concat(person)
      res.json(person)
    }else{
      res.status(406).send('Data incomplete')
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: Where is the initial duplication happening?

Comment: When I send a post request with a name that's already in the array it accepts it for the first time and then the second time it goes in sends the error, I want this to be avoided

Comment: I don't think the code you have written allow to add any duplicate but the better approach will be to have a person table with Unique constraint on the name field.